# Create svg arcs between two points

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I want to *connect* two SVG points (e.g. the centers of two circles) using arcs. If there is only one connection, the line (`<path>`) will be straight. If there are two connections, both will be rounded and will be symmetrical, this way:

[image]

So, in fact, there are few rules:

1. Everything should be symmetrical to to the imaginary line that connects the two points.
2. From 1, it's obvious that if the number of connections is:

   - odd: we do not display the straight line
   - even: we display the straight line
3. There should be a value `k` which defines the distance between two connections between same points.
4. The tangent that goes through the middle of the elliptical arc should be parallel with the straight line that connects the two points. And obviously, the middle of the line will be perpendicular to the tangent.

   [image]

I'm struggling to get a formula to calculate the `A` parameters in the `<path>` element.

What I did until now is:

```
<path d="M100 100, A50,20 0 1,0 300,100" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
```

- `M100 100` is clear: that's the starting point (*move to 100,100*)
- Last two numbers are also clear. The path ends in `300,100`
- I also saw that if I put `0` instead of `20`, I obtain a straight line.
- If I replace `1,0` with `1,1`, the path is flipped.

What I don't know is how to calculate the A parameters. I read [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands), but the imagine is still unclear to me. How to calculate these values?

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>

    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <!-- Connect A(100,100) with B(300, 100) -->
      <path d="M100 100, A50,0 0 1,0 300,100" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
      <path d="M100 100, A50,20 0 1,0 300,100" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
      <path d="M100 100, A50,20 0 1,1 300,100" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
      <path d="M100 100, A50,30 0 1,0 300,100" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
      <path d="M100 100, A50,30 0 1,1 300,100" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
      
      <!-- A(100, 100) B(300, 400) -->
      <path d="M100 100, A50,0 57 1,0 300,400" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
      <path d="M100 100, A50,20 57 1,0 300,400" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
      <path d="M100 100, A50,20 57 1,1 300,400" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm using SVG.js to create the paths.

Comment: Note that your "even number of connections" lines, by omitting the central line, result in the spacing between arcs of twice the spacing of the other arcs, in your sample picture. Maybe that's what you want, but it looks odd to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're making life very difficult for yourself by requiring circular arcs.

If you use quadratic curves instead, then the geometry becomes very simple — just offset the central X coordinate by half the difference in Y coordinates, and vice versa.

```js
function arc_links(dwg,x1,y1,x2,y2,n,k) {
  var cx = (x1+x2)/2;
  var cy = (y1+y2)/2;
  var dx = (x2-x1)/2;
  var dy = (y2-y1)/2;
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (i==(n-1)/2) {
      dwg.line(x1,y1,x2,y2).stroke({width:1}).fill('none');
    }
    else {
      dd = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
      ex = cx + dy/dd * k * (i-(n-1)/2);
      ey = cy - dx/dd * k * (i-(n-1)/2);
      dwg.path("M"+x1+" "+y1+"Q"+ex+" "+ey+" "+x2+" "+y2).stroke({width:1}).fill('none');
    }
  }
}

function create_svg() {
  var draw = SVG('drawing').size(300, 300);
  arc_links(draw,50,50,250,50,2,40);
  arc_links(draw,250,50,250,250,3,40);
  arc_links(draw,250,250,50,250,4,40);
  arc_links(draw,50,250,50,50,5,40);
  draw.circle(50).move(25,25).fill('#fff').stroke({width:1});
  draw.circle(50).move(225,25).fill('#fff').stroke({width:1});
  draw.circle(50).move(225,225).fill('#fff').stroke({width:1});
  draw.circle(50).move(25,225).fill('#fff').stroke({width:1});
}

create_svg();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.3.2/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really, you're awesome!

Comment: You will need to update your external js files as this no longer works.

Answer (score 7):

For drawing SVG path's arc you need 2 points and radius, there are 2 points and you just need to calculate radius for given distances.

Formula for radius:

`let r = (d, x) => 0.125*d*d/x + x/2;`

where:

`d` - distance between points

`x` - distance between arcs

it derived from **Pythagorean theorem**:

[image]

`a` here is a half of distance between points

---

```js
let r = (d, x) => !x?1e10:0.125*d*d/x + x/2; 

upd();

function upd() {
  let n = +count.value;
  let s = +step.value/10;
  let x1 = c1.getAttribute('cx'), y1 = c1.getAttribute('cy');
  let x2 = c2.getAttribute('cx'), y2 = c2.getAttribute('cy');
  let dx = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
  paths.innerHTML = [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => [
    n%2&&i===n-1?0:1+parseInt(i/2),
    i%2
  ]).map(i => `<path d="${[
    'M', x1, y1,
    'A', r(dx, s*i[0]), r(dx, s*i[0]), 0, 0, i[1], x2, y2
  ].join(' ')}"></path>`).join('');
}
```

```html
<input id="count" type="range" min=1 max=9 value=5 oninput=upd() >
<input id="step" type="range" min=1 max=200 value=100 oninput=upd() >
<svg viewbox=0,0,300,100 stroke=red fill=none >
  <circle id=c1 r=10 cx=50 cy=60></circle>
  <circle id=c2 r=10 cx=250 cy=40></circle>
  <g id=paths></g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that uses arcs, as asked for, rather than quadratic curves.

```
// Internal function
function connectInternal(x1,y1,x2,y2,con){
 var dx=x2-x1
 var dy=y2-y1
 var dist=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
 if(dist==0 || con==0){
  return "M"+x1+","+y1+"L"+x2+","+y2
 }
 var xRadius=dist*0.75
 var yRadius=dist*0.3*(con*0.75)
 var normdx=dx/dist
 if(normdx<-1)normdx=-1
 if(normdx>1)normdx=1
 var angle=Math.acos(normdx)*180/Math.PI
 if(x1>x2){
  angle=-angle
 }
 return "M"+x1+","+y1+"A"+xRadius+","+yRadius+","+
   angle+",00"+x2+","+y2+
   "M"+x1+","+y1+"A"+xRadius+","+yRadius+","+
   angle+",01"+x2+","+y2
}

// Returns an SVG path that represents
// "n" connections between two points.
function connect(x1,y1,x2,y2,n){
 var ret=""
 var con=n
 if(con%2==1){
  ret+=connectInternal(x1,y1,x2,y2,con)
  con-=1
 }
 for(var i=2;i<=con;i+=2){
  ret+=connectInternal(x1,y1,x2,y2,i)
 }
 return ret
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't meet the requirement of evenly spaced arc separation.